# Noun for "resolving" a problem

Tags: nouns

There is a certain problem (related to wireless computer networks) that can be **detected** and then **resolved**. I would like to name the chapter that I am writing about this problem using the corresponding nouns for these verbs:

> Detection and resolv...

I cannot come up with the noun for resolving. *Resolvation* doesn't sound like a word and *resolution* came to mind as well, but that is a whole different word.

Comment: Have you looked up _resolution_ in a dictionary? It has more than just the New Year sense.

Comment: Yeah, it's *resolution,* even though the meaning of it you're using is also different than pixel count.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

*Detection and Resolution* would work fine.

Comment: I answered in a 'comment' because the question is such that an 'answer' would encourage others like it.

Comment: Please explain your answer in full. Why would these work fine?